# Android support v7

Tags: android, android-support-library

I've recently got new laptop and downloaded new ADT for it. 2 months ago, I've started building application and already did much. But now new version of ADT force to make application always by using `ActionBarActivity` through android.support.v7 . So, my question is what should I do now? I have already `android-support-v4.jar` library in the project and am using it around 70% of all activities. Now when I'm creating new activity, it always creates one with the need of android-support-v7.jar (even for blank activities with static layout need) which I still don't have in project.

Should I just include new library in the project and continue working with android-support-v7 while making new activities and leave already done activities on v4 **or** I should make everything for v7 now, although 90% of application is done **or** I should just finish it with previous version of ADT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But now new version of ADT force to make application always by using ActionBarActivity through android.support.v7

The stock templates will give you `appcompat` and `ActionBarActivity`. That does not mean that "ADT force to make application always" -- at most, that is just the starting point. You are welcome to work on existing projects, import blank projects, etc. in addition to creating new projects with the new-project wizard.

Similarly, you do not need the new-activity wizard to add an activity.

> Should I just include new library in the project and continue working with android-support-v7 while making new activities and leave already done activities on v4 or I should make everything for v7 now, although 90% of application is done or I should just finish it with previous version of ADT?

Since your application is already in progress, you do not need to use either the new-project or new-activity wizards, and ADT will happily let you use whatever you want.

Comment: Yea, it's true I could always make it manually, but like it was pretty handy just to make it with ADT. Just to ask immediately - is it worse to make activity without fragment or why is it being pushed now to a sort of "standard"?

Comment: @Tommz: It is perfectly fine to create activities without fragments. Fragments are very useful, but they are not essential.